# Pretty print a pandas dataframe in VS Code

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, dataframe, visual-studio-code

I'd like to know if it's possible to display a pandas dataframe in VS Code while debugging (first picture) as it is displayed in PyCharm (second picture) ?

Thanks for any help.

---

*`df` print in vs code:*

[image: df print in vs code]

*`df` print in pycharm:*

[image: df print in pycharm]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As of the [January 2021 release](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-january-2021-release/#data-viewer-when-debugging) of the python extension, you can now view pandas dataframes with the built-in data viewer when debugging native python programs. When the program is halted at a breakpoint, right-click the dataframe variable in the variables list and select "View Value in Data Viewer"

[image: DataViewerWhenDebugging]

Comment: I wonder why this is only available in "Variables", not in "Watch". Sometimes it's more convenient to use "Watch", when there are too many local variables for example, and you need to retrieve the one you want. But great improvement anyway

Comment: Finally, I can see my DataFrame!

Comment: FYI, you need the "jupyter" extension, otherwise the option is not available

Comment: One danger here: the data viewer will round small values (beneath 1e10, looks like) to 0. Printing the dataframe directly will show them as expected.

Comment: How does one display the left panel with "VARIABLES"?

Comment: When I right click on a dataframe, in the viewer, I don't see a "View Value in Data Viewer" option.

Answer (score 15):

Tabulate is an excellent library to achieve fancy/pretty print of the pandas df:

information - link: [https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/]

Please follow following steps in order to achieve pretty print:
(Note: For easy illustration I will create simple dataframe in python)

1) install tabulate

```
pip install --upgrade tabulate
```

This statement will always install latest version of the tabulate library.

2) import statements

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
```

3) create simple temporary dataframe

```
temp_data = {'Name': ['Sean', 'Ana', 'KK', 'Kelly', 'Amanda'], 
        'Age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
        'Maths_Score': [67, 43, 65, 78, 97],
        'English_Score': [78, 98, 45, 67, 64]}
df = pd.DataFrame(temp_data, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Maths_Score', 'English_Score'])
```

4) without tabulate our dataframe print will be:

```
print(df)

    Name  Age  Maths_Score  English_Score
0    Sean   42           67             78
1     Ana   52           43             98
2      KK   36           65             45
3   Kelly   24           78             67
4  Amanda   73           97             64
```

5) after using tabulate your pretty print will be :

```
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

+----+--------+-------+---------------+-----------------+
|    | Name   |   Age |   Maths_Score |   English_Score |
|----+--------+-------+---------------+-----------------|
|  0 | Sean   |    42 |            67 |              78 |
|  1 | Ana    |    52 |            43 |              98 |
|  2 | KK     |    36 |            65 |              45 |
|  3 | Kelly  |    24 |            78 |              67 |
|  4 | Amanda |    73 |            97 |              64 |
+----+--------+-------+---------------+-----------------+
```

nice and crispy print, enjoy!!!  Please add comments, if you like my answer!

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, but I guessing people are looking for something like this - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111105

Comment: Tabulate works awesome for my huge DataFrame in VS Code!

Comment: Great answer, correct link is: https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/ (yours has a "]" at the end)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Shantanu's answer, Panda's [to_markdown](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html) function, which requires the [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) library installed in python, provides various plain text formatting for tables which show on VS Code editor, such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"animal_1": ["elk", "pig"], "animal_2": ["dog", "quetzal"]})
print(df.to_markdown())

|    | animal_1   | animal_2   |
|---:|:-----------|:-----------|
|  0 | elk        | dog        |
|  1 | pig        | quetzal    |
```

Answer (score 2):

- use [vs code jupyter notebooks support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_debug-a-jupyter-notebook)
- choose between [attach to local script](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_attach-to-a-local-script) or launch mode, up to you.
- include a `breakpoint()` where you want to break if using `attach` mode.
- when debugging use the [debug console](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-console-repl) to:

  ```
  display(df_consigne_errors)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a similar feature for VS Code. If you require this feature you might consider using Spyder IDE. [Spyder IDE Homepage](https://www.spyder-ide.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Use #%%% (number sign and 2 percentages) before your code; hit run, and you should get what you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).