# Where to find data viewer/varaible explorer in VS Code Insiders for Python Native Notebook?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Recently I switched from VS Code to the VS Code Insiders daily buildwith a much smoother Notebook experience and I'm loving it! However I can't find the Data viewer; the ability to view Dataframes.

Here's what I found out already;

- In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65883166/8433369) it mentions that in the Jan 2021 release a data viewer is available in the debugging section for Python but I can not get this to work with Native Notebooks.
- Tried finding more information in [vs-code/jupyter github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues) and get the impression that the functionality should already be present in Native Notebook version but that I am not able to locate it.
  FYI; This is how the data viewer looks like in the 'old' Jupyter Notebooks; [see screenshot of data viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNqGC.png)

Hope somebody can help me find it, so I don't need to switch back to the old notebooks.

Thanks,
Bart

Comment: Currently in VS Code insiders, it supports the "Variable explorer and data viewer" function of python files but cannot view the variables of Jupyter files. Therefore, I submitted this problem and let us expect it to get a feasible solution. Github link: [Does Jupyter notebook in VS Code insiders have "Variable explorer and data viewer" function.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4560)

Answer (score 0):

The data viewer and variable explorer will become available for Native Notebooks in the February release of the Jupyter extension (in a couple weeks' time). We appreciate your patience!

Comment: That's great news, thanks for sharing! Look forward to this release.