# VS Code - How to make data frames show in Excel format?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, sas

I am a  beginner in both Python and VS code but experienced in SAS. I'm writing Python code, primarily extracting data from a SQL server using SQL code and then transforming it via Python. Is there a way in VS code to see the entire dataframe so it shows in an Excel format (SAS has this option)? With over 50 variables, a print statement doesn't work for me and I would like to see all the observations (not many but often over 1000. I know, not efficient but it helps me. I'd rather not have to export the data to Excel every time.

Comment: What is "Excel format"? If by "dataframe" you mean a Pandas dataframe, and if you can run your code through the debugger, maybe this helps: [Pretty print a pandas dataframe in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52225216/2745495)

Comment: If that's not the same as what you want, it would help to [edit] to show a sample or screenshot of this "Excel format".

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate the "View in excel" functionality of SAS?  Or do you just mean view it in a tabular format that's sort of like excel?