# Visualize Dataframe in Pandas with VSCode

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

Hey guys I am working at the moment a lot with Pandas in VS-Code, and I saw that a DF in  Jupyter Notebook etc. looks way more nicer than it does in VS-Code. To be honest it looks preety messy in VS-Code. Thats the prettiest I could get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/njOZR.jpg While it looks something like that in Jupyter etc. : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFARV.jpg Thats way more beautiful! Is there away how to get this too look something similiar like this? Even with a lot of columns like in my case 57? I am using the latest Python, Pandas and VS-Code version.

Comment: For visualizing and maniuplating data using pandas I suggest working with jupyter notebooks, You can't beautify much the output you show on a terminal, which is necessary in ds.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65883166

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65864298/1582413

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View dataframe while debugging in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097076/view-dataframe-while-debugging-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Microsoft Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python), which adds support to notebooks.

Then, you can preview inline.

[image]

Or you can explore the dataset.
[image]