# How to print dataframe in VS Code notebooks without print (or tabulate)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code

Is it possible for VS Code notebooks to display my pandas dataframe the same way it does alone as when running in a loop?

If I call `df` at the end of a cell, I get a beautiful output

```py
df
```

[image: Beautiful output of dataframe]

I'm making many dataframes in a loop and want to inspect them. But the output doesn't look very nice.

```py
for i in range(N):
    df = make_df(N)
    print(df)
```

[image: Ugly output]

Eww. It even goes over 2 lines :(

I have read through this question - [Pretty print a pandas dataframe in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225216/pretty-print-a-pandas-dataframe-in-vs-code) - and the `tabulate` package is helpful but it isn't the same as native VS Code output.

Comment: I personally like selecting the option if you right click on your code to "Run Current File in Python Interactive Window", then in the interactive window you can click on the button that looks like a table "Show variables active in jupyter kernal", then you can double click to show any dataframe stored as a variable. I think that might help

Comment: What happens in VSCode if you switch out `print(df)` with `display(df)`

Comment: @smichael_44 I can't find those options when I right click a cell in a jupyter notebook

Comment: @lummers ahh! `display(df)` is what I was after!

Comment: @lummers For the last year and a half I've been using `print()` in jupyter on vscode and didn't know about `display`. Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you swap out `print(df)` for just `df`? If you only get the last one, you might want to change the `ast_node_interactivity`. See [How to configure IPython to execute cell blocks the same way as a plain Python REPL does?](/q/54136057/4518341) And for why it does that, see [IPython and REPL behave differently when displaying data without the print function](/q/46029070/4518341).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an answer here as it helped the OP:

You can use:

```
display(df)
```

From the documentation:

> Display a Python object in all frontends.
>
> By default all representations will be computed and sent to the frontends. Frontends can decide which representation is used and how.
>
> In terminal IPython this will be similar to using print(), for use in richer frontends see Jupyter notebook examples with rich display logic.

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html